# what does it mean: Let X and Y be the numbers of extractions in which the first heart and the first clover come out respectively

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Cards are repeatedly drawn from a deck of poker cards with replacement. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the numbers
of extractions in which the first heart and the first clover come out respectively.
Calculate The joint probability function $p_{X, Y}$

I know how to get the joint probability, but what does it mean: Let X and Y be the numbers of extractions in which the first heart and the first clover come out respectively how I interpret that mathematically, being with replacement $x, y \in [1, \infty )$ that it comes out on the first occasion or that it never comes out? I want to know What values can (x, y) take?

Comment: You are correct that $x$ and $y$ can both take any integer value.

Comment: @5xum and then how the joint probability function is obtained?, I would extract it case by case

Comment: "clover" presumably what is more usually called "[clubs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clubs#See_also)" in English

Comment: Let's focus on $X$ first. You have a deck of cards and take one card, and check if the suit of the card is hearts. If it is you're done (number of extractions is $1$), but if it's not, you put back the card in the deck and randomly take another card. If it's hearts you're done (number of extractions is $2$), and if it's not, you put it back in  and so on. Now, $Y$ counts the same thing but for the clubs suit, so that $X,Y \in \{1,2,\ldots\}$. Thus, $\mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y)$ tells you the probability that the number of extractions until first heart is $x$ AND extractions until first clubs is $y$.

Comment: @Bergson ok, but then how do you get the marginal probability function since the possible outcomes are infinite

Comment: @kiedwicks infinite possible outcomes are a common occurrence in probability. For your question at hand, it might help you to look at the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).